# calculate the modulus of a fraction with big numbers

Tags: java

I have two big numbers (<10^9) `n` and `m`. I have to calculate `[(n-1+m)!]/[(n-1)!*m!]`
if the answer is too big I have to get the modulus from `(10^9+7)`. (ex : n%mod if n is too large that mod).

```
 int mod = 1000000000+7;
```

I calculated it like below. (I  calculated the upper half and bottom half separately)

```
    long up=1;
    for (long i = a+b-1; i>=Math.max(a, b); i--) {
        up*=i%mod;            
    }
    up=up%mod;
    long down=1;
    for (long i = Math.min(a, b); i>0; i--) {
        down*=i%mod;            
    }
```

then print the answer as

```
System.out.println((up%mod/down%mod)%mod);
```

Is this approach correct. Will  it gives the correct out put.

I know `(a*b*c)%d == [(a%d)*(b%d)*(c%d)]%d` (correct me if i'm wrong)

So is there any way like that to calculate `[a/b]%d` ?

Comment: I have a feeling you don't need to calculate the division explicitly since I think the result is an integer. You might just need to work out the math and write an explicit product (then use the modulo multiplication).

Comment: It is in fact a binomial [coefficient which](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) is integer. You can use one of the methods described on wikipedia (see the multiplicative formula).

Answer (score 1):

```
(a/b) % c != ((a%c) / (b%c) % c)
```

Instead use recursive formula of [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula) to calculate the modulus

```
(n, k) = (n - 1, k - 1) + (n - 1, k)
```

In your case it will be

```
(n - 1 + m, m) % MOD = ((n - 2 + m, m - 1) % MOD + (n - 2 + m, m) % MOD) % MOD
```

use above recursion to get the result.